# How do I make Selenium to launch Chrome with default profile?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I'm trying to get Selenium to launch Chrome with my default profile but fail. for some reason, the window will launch itself with no profile logged in:

```
from selenium import  webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Me/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

Comment: Try removing the `/Default` from the path

Comment: Looks like this answers your question: https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile